# How to update Google Drive file using byte range

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to understand how the Google API works server side in order to allow me to implement my own type of resumable upload.  I understand that I can use the MediaFileUpload or MediaInMemoryUpload mechanism, but I am looking for something much more raw.  For example, I want to deliberately upload 1k from a file, then later on (like days later), append another 1k of the file.  Obviously not real figures here, but hopefully you get the idea.  Well here is where I am with the code:

```
headers = {
    'range': 'bytes=%d-%d' % (
        offset,
        offset + len(data)
    )
}
body = {
    'title': "MyFile.bin",
    'description': "",
    'modifiedDate': datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
    'mimeType': 'application/octet-stream',
    'parents': [{ 'id': parentId }]
}
res = http.request(
    url, method="PUT", body=body, headers=headers
).execute()
```

So as you can see, it is clear where you specify the parameters for the file (file attributes) and the header specification for the request.  But where do you specify the actual data stream to be uploaded in that request?  Is it the case that I can just specify a media_body in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible and is not formally on Google's roadmap to introduce this functionality.  The only way to append to a file is to update the entire file again from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a multipart HTTP request which is explained on https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#multipart

I'd recommend you to use our [JS client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/) and use the [existing implementation on the API reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) right under the JavaScript tab.

Comment: Well not quite.  You see, I am trying to upload an arbitrary chunk.  A multipart request is not necessary here since the file already exists on in Google Drive.  I am merely trying to append a chunk of data to it within the specified range (note the header object).  Also, this is Python not JavaScript.

Comment: I have found a few other posts from people trying to do similar.  It seems appending to a file is not currently supported or in Google's roadmap.